# Angular Security hack - how to fix when someone can edit javascript to show button

Tags: javascript, c#, angularjs, asp.net-mvc

So I just noticed that someone is logging in and then figured out that they can use the use F12 and change OfficeAdmin from False to True ...

The C# razor  / Angular is set like this

```
<script language="javascript">

    angular.module('portal')
        .value('userCtx', {
            userName: "@SessionVars.UserName",
            userVendorId: "@SessionVars.LoggedInVendorId",
            userOfficeId: "@SessionVars.LoggedInOfficeId",
            isClientAdmin: "@SessionVars.IsClientAdmin",
            isVendorAdmin: "@SessionVars.IsVendorAdmin",
            isOfficeAdmin: "@SessionVars.IsOfficeAdmin",
            securityLevel: "@SessionVars.SecurityLevel"
        });
</script>
```

Comment: Add server side validation to any API calls that require admin permissions.

Comment: You should never EVER rely on client-side obfuscation for security.  Rather, the only purpose of clientside security is simply to guide users in the right direction and remove functionality they don't have access to for usability purposes and nothing more.